# Произведение аргументов, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным аргументами

Tags: python

*Условие задачи:* Напишите функцию, принимающую произвольное количество аргументов, и возвращающую произведение аргументов, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным аргументами. Если функции передается пустой список аргументов, то она должна возвращать значение `None`. В процессе решения не использовать преобразования конструкции `*args` в список или иную структуру данных.

```
def min_max(*args):
    composition = 1
    max_arg = args[0]
    max_ind = 0
    min_arg = args[0]
    min_ind = 0
    # Проходит по списку и вычисляет max и min
    for i, item in enumerate(args):
        if item > max_arg:
            max_arg = item
            max_ind = i
        if item < min_arg:
            min_arg = item
            min_ind = i
    for i in args[min_ind:max_ind]:
        composition *= i
    return composition


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg = list(map(float, input('Введите список аргументов: ').split()))
    print("Произведение аргументов, расположенных"
          " между минимальным и максимальным аргументами:  ",
          min_max(*arg))
```

Проблема: если попытаться вывести пустой список, выдает ошибку `IndexError`, подскажите как можно решить и в чем ошибка?

Comment: В самом начале добавить проверку: `if not args: return None`

Comment: Ещё одна ошибка - `for i in args[min_ind:max_ind]:` подразумевает, что минимальный аргумент идёт раньше максимального. Кроме того, минимальный входит в произведение, а максимальный - нет - неаккуратненько как-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идиоматичная проверка на пустой кортеж, список и т.п. в питоне выглядит так:

```
def min_max(*args):
    if not args:
        return None
```

Здесь используется тот факт, что приведение пустой коллекции к булевому типу даёт `False`.

Проверять на нулевую длину или совпадение с пустым кортежем тоже можно, но это выглядит не так красиво и понятно, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

все потому что вы сразу лезете в `args[0]`, которого не существует

используйте проверку вначале на пустые параметры:

```
def min_max(*args):
    if args == ():
          return None
```

или

```
def min_max(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
          return None
```

Comment: спасибо большое. запомнил

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в начало функции

```
if len(args) == 0:
    return None
```